# Useage of variables in XML file

Tags: php, xml, variables, charts

My XML file look like this:

```
<?xml versiion="1.0" encoding "utf-8"?>

<graph caption='chart' xAxisName='songs' yAxisName='votes' showNames='0' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0'>
 <set name='song name' value='1233' color='AFD8F8' />
 <set name='song name' value='857' color='F6BD0F' />
 <set name='song name' value='671' color='8BBA00' />
 <set name='song name' value='494' color='FF8E46' />
 <set name='song name' value='761' color='008E8E' />
 <set name='song name' value='960' color='D64646' />
 <set name='song name' value='629' color='8E468E' />
 <set name='song name' value='622' color='588526' />
 <set name='song name' value='376' color='B3AA00' />
 <set name='song name' value='494' color='008ED6' />
 <set name='song name' value='761' color='9D080D' />
 <set name='song name' value='960' color='A186BE' />
</graph>
```

Can I use variables in this file in the value='$variable'???

help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use PHP variables if the XML is handled through PHP. In simple terms, just change the extension from .xml to .php, set the content type to xml using `header('Content-type: text/xml')`. Then you can use the file as it was a normal PHP file:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); echo '<?'; ?>xml version="1.0" encoding "utf-8"<?php echo '?>'; ?>

<graph caption='chart' xAxisName='songs' yAxisName='votes' showNames='0' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0'>
<?php foreach($songs as $song): ?>
    <set name='<?php echo $song['name']; ?>' value='<?php echo $song['value']; ?>' color='<?php echo $song['color']; ?>' />
<?php endforeach; ?>
</graph>
```

Comment: Not if `short_tags` is enabled in the PHP engine.. You need to `<?php echo "<?"; ?>xml [...]`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can:

```
<set name='song name' value='<?php echo $variable;?>' color='588526' />
```

Comment: No you can't if the XML file is not parsed with PHP - if the file is a raw .xml file, then this will obviously fail if the server is not set up to handle .xml's through PHP.

Comment: He didn't say it was a .xml file, did he? =/

Comment: Thank you all very much - The problem solved!!! (-:
Emil, yours was the most elegant and simple, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

XML is a text file. You can put whatever text you want into it, but variables don't make sense in this context.

What are you using the XML file for?

Comment: @Oded, apparently he's using the XML to create a flash graph dynamically, using for example this library: <http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/>